# Cast 4-dimensional array to square matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose that $T$ is an array with dimensions

```
dimensions(T)
{2, 2, m, m}
```

[image]

Comment: For moderators: I'm using a picture instead of latex because I was receiving the error `Post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted...`. It seems that some of the displayed equations are somehow (mis)interpreted as malformed code (see for instance [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/post-without-code-supposed-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted)).

Comment: Can you add code for any attempts you have made at solving this problem?

Comment: I think `ArrayFlatten` will do this, immediately...

Comment: A minimal example with the large 4D matrix and desired output matrix would help in providing a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @march pointed out in a comment, this is exactly what `ArrayFlatten` is for. Here's an example:

```
s = Function[x, Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {3, 3}]];
t = {{s[a], s[b]}, {s[c], s[d]}};

Dimensions[t]
(* {2,2,3,3} *)

ArrayFlatten[t] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Output of <code>ArrayFlatten[t]</code> in <code>MatrixForm</code>]